# To the power of n/2 - how to get rid of it.

Tags: power-series

In short, I have a formula $ \frac{2}{3}((-2)^{\frac{n}{2}}-1) $

I need to get rid of (n/2). I have to make sure that I only raise the number with degree n, the integer part, not n/2. Any ideas?

Comment: Replace $-2$ with $(i\sqrt{2})^2$.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to raise (-2) to the power of n.

Answer (score 2):

$$(-2)^{\frac{n}{2}}=(-2)^{\frac{1}{2}n}=((-2)^{\frac{1}{2}})^n=(\sqrt{-2})^n=(\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{2})^n=(i\cdot\sqrt{2})^n$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2}{3}\left((-2)^{\frac{n}{2}}-1\right) = \frac{2}{3}\left(\sqrt{(-2)^n}-1\right)$$